# Axios Get Request In Pinia Store Will Fetch Data But Params Do Not Show In URL?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pinia

I can fetch data fine when using axios inside my Laravel Pinia project, but the URL parameters won't show up in the url? Here is my code:

```
getters: {
    axiosParams() {
        window.csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('_token', csrfToken);
        params.append('q', this.q);
        params.append('availableNamesOnly', this.filters.availableNamesOnlyEnabled);
        params.append('selectedTlds', Object.assign({}, this.filters.selectedTlds));
        params.append('priceRange', this.filters.priceRange);

        return params;
    }
},
```

Next is my method to fetch the data:

```
actions: {
    fetchSearchResults() {
        self = this;

        axios.get('/search/', {
            params: self.axiosParams,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            self.results.defaultResults = response.data.defaultResults;
            self.results.allEndingsResults = response.data.allEndingsResults;
            self.results.aiResults = response.data.aiResults;
            self.results.seoResults = response.data.seoResults;
            self.results.funResults = response.data.funResults;
            self.results.mixResults = response.data.mixResults;
            self.results.hasResults = response.data.hasResults;
            self.results.display = response.data.display;
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
            // always executed
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: Which url bar? The question clear problem statement

Comment: I am sorry I mean the url you can see in the browser window, usually at the top of the window.

Comment: You aren't supposed to see urls for AJAX request there. If your intention is to navigate to this url then you chose a wrong way to do this, check what `fetch` actually does